# Big Screenshot of Node-Tree

Tags: node-editor

Would it be possible to screen capture or output node-tree network like really big, bigger than actual monitor screen. If possible, a way to capture the node-tree boundary.

So far, I only screen shot limited to my monitor.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13):

While its undoubtedly possible to do some tricks to make a huge screen-shot *(automate panning and capturing the view, then joining up the tiles)*, Blender has nothing built-in to perform such an operation.

Answer (score 0):

A custom addon has been built for this purpose called PrintTree. You can find it here: https://github.com/Yeetus3141/PrintNodes/

Unfortunately though for Blender 3.0 a custom build of blender is required for the addon to work correctly for some strange reason.